# Network calls inside custom validations in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-validation

I need to validate a number of fields in my REST Api. Is there a specific pattern to do this ? My api is cluttered with these validation calls.

1. Check auth token in the http request against another service to verify access permissions.
2. Validate a number of fields in request body such as category, type etc by making calls to another service.
3. Generic null & empty checks. Currently I'm using spring validation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Check auth token in the http request against another service to verify access permissions

I would suggest validating the token in a filter before the request reaches the controller.

Something like this

1. Create a new token validation filter

```java
    @Component
    public class TokenValidationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        private TokenValidationService tokenValidationService;
    
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    
            final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            
          boolean isValid = tokenValidationService.validate(authorizationHeader);
            //do authentication here 
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Add the filter to http filters

```java
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); // this just an example you might needed to added before a different filter 
    }
}
```

> Validate a number of fields in request body such as category, type etc by making calls to another service.

Spring allows creating custom constraints. See spring [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-spring-constraints).

Example:
UniqueUsername interface

```java
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueUsernameValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueUsername {
    String message() default "username is not unique";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```java
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, UserDto> {
    private final UserService usersService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(UniqueUsername constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(UserDto value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       return usersService.isUnique(value.getUsername());
    }

}
```

user dto:

```
@UniqueUsername(message = "Username is used")
public class UserDto {
    @DecimalMin(value = "0")
    private long id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Username can not be blank")
    private String username;
}
```

Note that the constraints could be class level like UniqueUsername or filed level like NotBlank.

> Generic null & empty checks. Currently I'm using spring validation to do this.

spring validation/constraints is correct.